# Cypher - conditional where clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to update a users subject name either by id or by name.
Currently the query I have is this:

```
 MATCH (s:Subject)-[:REGISTERED-BY]->(u:User{id: 1})
 WHERE s.name="Math" or s.id=""
 SET s.name = "Maths"
 RETURN s
```

If I only use the name without `OR`, it works.
If I only use ID and leave name as an empty string it works.
But if I use the name and leave id empty in the OR clause. The update doesn't happen
I need to conditionally update the names, depending on whether the name is available or the id. The id field is a UUID.
Is there a way to write that logic in the query itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you, In Neo4j you can perform conditional operations using two options.

If you have access to APOC, then you can use [`APOC.do.when`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.do/apoc.do.when/):

```
MATCH (s:Subject)-[:REGISTERED-BY]->(u:User{id: 1})

WHERE ...

CALL apoc.do.when(s.name="Math", "SET s.name = \"Maths\"", "", {}) YIELD value as _

RETURN s
```

The second is a more native [`FOREACH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/foreach/):

```
MATCH (s:Subject)-[:REGISTERED-BY]->(u:User{id: 1})

WHERE ...

FOREACH(_ IN CASE s.name WHEN "Math" THEN [1] ELSE [] END | SET s.name = "Maths" )

RETURN s
```

Comment: Thank you!
But can you please clarify how the FOREACH check whether c.ID is given or c.Name to updated based on one or the other?

Comment: @DaveM using the FOREACH, you could: `_ IN CASE s.name WHEN NOT NULL`